# How do read xml file using python and display data in table format?

Tags: python, xml, automation

How to read `xml` file and display data into table format   ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<issue>
<TABLE-A>
<EMPNO>1</EMPNO>
<ENAME>A</ENAME>
<SAL>100</SAL>
</TABLE-A>
<TABLE-B>
<ADDRESSID>AD1</ADDRESSID>
<STREET>A</STREET>
<PINCODE>11111</PINCODE>
</TABLE-B>
</issue>
```

Comment: Would a `pandas` dataframe be an acceptable output?

Answer (score 0):

If its just this simple, I'd use `xmltodict` and `pandas`

```
import xmltodict as xml
import pandas as pd

with open("data.xml", "r") as f:
    raw_data = xml.parse(f.read())

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(raw_data["issue"])
print(data)
```

```
          TABLE-A TABLE-B
EMPNO           1     NaN
ENAME           A     NaN
SAL           100     NaN
ADDRESSID     NaN     AD1
STREET        NaN       A
PINCODE       NaN   11111
```

Comment: Thanks @flakes for help. I have another scenario like 

How can we create two data frame Def_A(from Table A)  and Def_B(from Table B) . I would be great if you share code .